# How to implement STTP SSL requests with HttpClientZioBackend? (SCALA/ZIO)

Tags: scala, zio, sttp

I am using [SttpAPI](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/index.html) to send http requests, for one of my requests I need to use [mutual SSL](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/conf/ssl.html#mutual-ssl) and i'm failing to find instructions how to implement it.

My backend is HttpClientZioBackend and there is no documentation for customizing the SSL Context for this kind of backend.

I will appreciate any help or samples.

Answer (score 1):

val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(ssl).build()
HttpClientZioBackend.usingClient(client = httpClient, ...)